# Restoring Tensorflow Model ways difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, model

I have seen and tried two methods but could not understand what difference does it makes. Here are the two methods I used:
**Method 1:**

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)+".meta")

sess  = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) 
if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))):
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path) + "Session Loaded for Testing")
```

**Method 2:**

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess  =tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())    
if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))):
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
        print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path) + "Session Loaded for Testing")
```

What I want to know is:

> What is the difference between the above two methods?
>   Which is the best method to load the model?

Please let me know what is your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to be as concise as possible so here are my 2 cents on the matter. I will comment on the important lines of your code to point out what I think.

```
# Importing the meta graph is same as building the same graph from scratch
# creating the same variables, creating the same placeholders and ect.
# Basically you are only importing the graph definition
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)+".meta")

sess  = tf.Session()
# Absolutely no need to initialize the variables here. They will be initialized
# when the you restore the learned variables.
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) 
if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))):
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path) + "Session Loaded for Testing")
```

As for the second method:

```
# You can't create a saver object like this, you will get an error "No variables to save", which is true.
# You haven't created any variables. The workaround for doing this is:
# saver = tf.train.Saver(defer_build=True) and then after building the graph
# ....Graph building code goes here....
# saver.build()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
# Absolutely no need to initialize the variables here. They will be initialized
# when the you restore the learned variables. 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())    
if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))):
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path) + "Session Loaded for Testing")
```

So nothing wrong with the first approach but the second one is flat-out not correct. Don't get me wrong with this, but I don't like either of them. However, this is just a personal taste. What I want to do on the other hand, is the following:

```
# Have a class that creates the model and instantiate an object of that class
my_trained_model = MyModel()
# This is basically the same as what you are doing with
# saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)+".meta")
# Then, once I have the graph build, I will create a saver object
saver = tf.train.Saver()
# Then I will create a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore the trained variables here
    saver.restore(sess, model_checkpoint_path)
    # Now I can do whatever I want with the my_trained_model object
```

I hope that this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Will any of the methods give different results? Or the same result?

Comment: Well, the correct result is that all method return the variables in the same condition as they were saved. So yes, all methods will return the same result.